How to serialize custom type?
I am trying to access GridGain server from the project that’s written in C++ using GridGain C++ thin client: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/cpp-thin-client
As long as I use basic types (integers, std::string etc.) everything works fine.
However, more complex types (any kind of “struct”-ures) require serialization. Serialization is outlined here:  https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/cpp-specific/cpp-serialization . That page seems to be giving pieces of the code but not a complete example. If I try to just copy and compile code from that page:
class Address
{
  friend struct ignite::binary::BinaryType<Address>;
public:
  Address() { }

  Address(const std::string& street, int32_t zip) :
  street(street), zip(zip) { }

  const std::string& GetStreet() const
  {
    return street;
  }

  int32_t GetZip() const
  {
    return zip;
  }

private:
  std::string street;
  int32_t zip;
};

template<>
struct ignite::binary::BinaryType<Address>
{
  static int32_t GetTypeId()
  {
    return GetBinaryStringHashCode("Address");
  }

  static void GetTypeName(std::string& name)
  {
    name = "Address";
  }

  static int32_t GetFieldId(const char* name)
  {
    return GetBinaryStringHashCode(name);
  }

  static bool IsNull(const Address& obj)
  {
    return obj.GetZip() && !obj.GetStreet().empty();
  }

  static void GetNull(Address& dst)
  {
    dst = Address();
  }

  static void Write(BinaryWriter& writer, const Address& obj)
  {
    writer.WriteString("street", obj.GetStreet());
    writer.WriteInt32("zip", obj.GetZip());
  }

  static void Read(BinaryReader& reader, Address& dst)
  {
    dst.street = reader.ReadString("street");
    dst.zip = reader.ReadInt32("zip");
  }
};

It gives compilation errors:

\ggainserializer.h(75): error C2027: use of undefined type 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
\install\gridgain\include\ignite\impl\binary\binary_reader_impl.h(46): note: see declaration of 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
\ggainserializer.h(76): error C2027: use of undefined type 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
\install\gridgain\include\ignite\impl\binary\binary_reader_impl.h(46): note: see declaration of 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
4>GGainSerializer.cpp
...

The API is based on the templates and seems like something is missing.
Has anyone been able to get serialization of the custom C++ types work? ? If so please kindly provide a sample piece of code that writes to and reads from Ignite (or GridGain which is the same) using serializer for custom types – C++ “struct”-ures. That code should ideally be complete so that I can compile it and step through (debug).
Thank you.
Again, we have tried following instructions here https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/cpp-specific/cpp-serialization but they don't seem to work.

Have you tried examples? https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/put-get-example/src/put_get_example.cpp

@Pavel,
Thank you very much for the link! Looking at it as well as at the other files in the repo I finally was able to get my GridGain/Ignite custom type serialization work. It took me a week of struggles to get here so will outline the issues I’ve faced and solutions since it might help others:

The only official Ignite/GridGain documentation on C++ serialization for custom types I was able to find is: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/cpp-specific/cpp-serialization . Unfortunately, if does not refer to those code samples in the repo you’ve kindly provided. And in my opinion those samples are the key.

The code in the above documentation has bug which causes GridGain server to throw exception.
static bool IsNull(const Address& obj)
{
return obj.GetZip() && !obj.GetStreet().empty();
}


Should be:
return !(obj.GetZip() && !obj.GetStreet().empty());


The link you’ve kindly provided ( https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/put-get-example/src/put_get_example.cpp ) refers to files here: https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/include/ignite/examples (specifically to “ignite/examples/organization.h”) . Those 3 files include different headers and it is unclear which header is needed in clients’ code. So in my code apparently I was including different headers causing compilation issues. Correct header that has to be included is "ignite/binary/binary.h". Documentation noted in (1) above unfortunately does not make that point clear either.
Since I am using Thin Client for C++ the best example is actually https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/cpp/examples/thin-client-put-get-example/src/thin_client_put_get_example.cpp ,  but the link you provided helps a lot also.

Since you are obviously a member of Ignite team (according to your commits in the above Git repo) please kindly help us by clarifying the following:

Do you know a good link to GridGain/Ignite documentation outlining the differences between C++ Thin and Thick client capabilities and, most importantly, APIs? If so, please kindly provide since I couldn’t find any.
What is the purpose of BinaryTypeDefaultAll base class used in many above examples? The only documentation I found https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/cppdoc/structignite_1_1binary_1_1BinaryTypeDefaultAll.html does not tell much.
For the class BinaryType could you please explain the need for methods:
a)  GetTypeName() . Is there a way to extract the same name programmatically?
b)  GetTypeId() . Similarly, is there a way to extract the same name programmatically?
c)  IsNull() . According to my tests if this method returns true during cache.put() operation, the server (or C++ client) throws exception refusing to persist the object (value).
Again, the only available documentation for that class/API https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/cppdoc/structignite_1_1binary_1_1BinaryType_3_01T_01_5_01_4.html does not seem to explain much.

Sincere apologies for asking so many questions. C++ documentation seems to be incomplete. So short of digging though Ignite/GridGain code the only options are to ask Ignite team members or support.
Thank you very much again!
